# Speed up matrix operations

Tags: r, matrix, apply

I have two matrices of the same dimensions (which in reality are of 2,500 x 15,000):

```
set.seed(1)
a.mat <- matrix(rnorm(25*150),nrow=25,ncol=150,dimnames=list(paste0("p",1:25),paste0("c",1:150)))
b.mat <- matrix(rnorm(25*150),nrow=25,ncol=150,dimnames=list(paste0("p",1:25),paste0("c",1:150)))
```

And I'm computing this with them:

```
res.mat <- do.call(cbind,lapply(1:ncol(a.mat),function(i){
  t.mat <- a.mat-a.mat[,i]
  t.mat <- log10(abs(t.mat)+1) * sign(t.mat)
  return(suppressWarnings(cor(t.mat,b.mat[,i])))
}))
```

Any idea if and how this can done faster than the way I'm currently doing it? Perhaps running it in parallel with `multidplyr`?

Per `multidplyr, here's what I'm attempting:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:ncol(a.mat),function(i){
    cbind(reshape2::melt(a.mat) %>% dplyr::rename(id=Var1,cell=Var2,a.value=value),
          do.call("rbind",replicate(ncol(a.mat),data.frame(cell.i=colnames(a.mat)[i],a.value.i=a.mat[,i]),simplify=F)),
          do.call("rbind",replicate(ncol(a.mat),data.frame(b.value.i=b.mat[,i]),simplify=F)))
  })) %>% dplyr::mutate(t.value=a.value-a.value.i) %>% dplyr::mutate(t.value=log10(abs(t.value)+1)*sign(t.value)) %>% dplyr::group_by(cell.i)
```

And then:

```
group.size <- 3
n.groups <- ceiling(ncol(a.mat)/group.size)

for(i in 1:n.groups){
  start.idx <- (i-1)*group.size+1
  end.idx <- min(i*group.size,ncol(a.mat))
  current.df <- df %>% dplyr::filter(cell.i %in% colnames(a.mat)[start.idx:end.idx])
  current.df <- current.df %>% multidplyr::partition(cell.i) %>% multidplyr::cluster_library("tidyverse") %>% multidplyr::cluster_library("MASS") %>%
    multidplyr::cluster_assign_value("myFunction", myFunction) %>%
    do(results = myFunction(.)) %>% dplyr::collect() %>% .$results %>% dplyr::bind_rows()
}
```

Where:

```
myFunction <- function(df)
{
  return(df %>% dplyr::group_by(e.cell) %>% dplyr::mutate(cor=cor(t.value,b.value.i)))
}
```

However, this hits this error message:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) :
  3 nodes produced errors; first error: Can't convert an environment to function
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
In addition: Warning message:
group_indices_.grouped_df ignores extra arguments
```

So, is using `multidplyr` this way even worth it? and if so any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I doubt it. You're using really basic functions, but need 15,000x15,000 correlations, so no surprise that it takes some time. In fact, you can rewrite the `do.call + cbind + lapply` as a `for` loop to gain some readability without any loss of speed.

Comment: It's possible that your code is doing what you want, but since you never said what the goal was, ... we are at a disadvantage in offering assistance.

Comment: Yeah, I can't really think of any other way of describing it other than the operations I'm going through. It is eventually meant to estimate flow of particles, but that's a several steps downstream to this computation.

Comment: `multidplyr` is made for data frames. In general, matrices are simpler than data frames and simple numeric calculations on matrices are much more efficient than the same operations on data frames. You could look at parallel processing with other packages. You could also use an R installation with a more optimized BLAS than the default, might speed up the `cor` step.

Comment: Thanks @Gregor. I was thinking of `melt`ing `a.mat` `ncol(a.mat)` time to a `data.frame` where another column would be `a.mat[,i]` over each column `i` and the last column will be `b.mat[,i]` over each column `i`. The last column would be the column `i` indicator, and that way I'll be able to run it in parallel using `multidplyr` splitting it by the column `i` indicator.

Comment: It will be much slower. Matrices are *fast* compared to data frames. You can run in parallel with, e.g., `foreach` or `snowfall`, and keep everything in matrices.